# How do I read a .csv file for a tile map in pygame?

Tags: python, csv, game-development, tile

I'm making a sequel to an entry I made in the GMTK Game Jam. It's a platformer where the player has to get through randomly selected maps of various game modes, like a platforming race, a boss battle, and what I can only describe as dodgeball but with a giant killer pac man. For this, I want to make many levels, and slowly editing lists in a python script isn't gonna cut it for this. So I want to learn how to read .csv files and use them to create a level using many tiles. But how would I go about this?

So far I have a main script, a script for sprites, and a levels script. The last one has two test level maps inside of it, and I want to replace it with a folder of various .csv files. In my main script, I have a game class. In the `__init__` method, I set a list of levels pulling from the level script, randomly choose one to load, and loop through it to create a sprite from my sprites script when the index is a certain value.

```
#Set tile map
        self.level = [levels.plat_lvl_1, levels.plat_lvl_2]

        self.tile_map = random.choice(self.level)

        for i in range(len(self.tile_map)):
            for j in range(len(self.tile_map[i])):
                if self.tile_map[i][j] == 1:
                    sprites.Tile(j * 32, i * 32, 1, self.tile_group)

                elif self.tile_map[i][j] == 2:
                    sprites.Tile(j * 32, i * 32, 2, self.tile_group, self.platform_group)

                elif self.tile_map[i][j] == 3:
                    sprites.Tile(j * 32, i * 32, 3, self.tile_group, self.platform_group)

                elif self.tile_map[i][j] == 4:
                    sprites.Tile(j * 32, i * 32, 4, self.tile_group, self.platform_group)

                elif self.tile_map[i][j] == 5:
                    self.player = sprites.Player(j * 32, i * 32, self.player_group, self.platform_group)

                elif self.tile_map[i][j] == 6:
                    sprites.Tile(j * 32, i * 32 - 32, 6, self.tile_group)
```

How would I replace a list with a .csv file, and how would I need to loop through it or strip it or whatever in order to properly create my levels? [Here is the link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yUwWdcvwyr9rohlL6e19xvo9NWWeP_OO/view?usp=sharing) to the entire project as it is currently if you need it.

Thank you very much!

-Dominic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this function to convert csv maps to a List[List[int]] format.

```
def convert_csv_to_2d_list(csv_file: str):
    tile_map = []
    with open(csv_file, "r") as f:
        for map_row in csv.reader(f):
            tile_map.append(list(map(int, map_row)))
    return tile_map
```

Its usage will then be:

```
self.tile_map = convert_csv_to_2d_list(csv_file="csv_file_location.csv")
for row in range(len(self.tile_map)):
    for col in range(len(self.tile_map[row])):
        # specific codes follows here
```

Comment: I tried using your function, but apparently the line for appending a value to the tile map has an error, and I don't think I can fix it. Here is the exact error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: You are most likely using strings inside your csv file. This is a quick fix inside the ```convert_csv_to_2d_list``` function: ```tile_map.append(map_row)``` instead of ```tile_map.append(list(map(int, map_row)))```

Comment: Thanks! One last thing though, for some reason my game class doesn't recognize the player variable when I set it. I use 'if self.tile_map[row][col] == 5:
                    self.player = sprites.Player(row * 32, col * 32, self.player_group, self.platform_group)' but it returns an error saying "AttributeError: Game object has no attribute Player". Do you know why this results when I attempt to use this method?

Comment: You may have to post that as another question and show more details. It's a bit difficult to imagine your game architecture based only from few info you shared.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
import csv

with open('level_file.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
   
    for row in csv_reader:
        for column in range(len(row)):
            if row[column] == 1:
                #do sprite stuff
                sprites.Tile(column * 32, row * 32, 1, self.tile_group)

            elif row[column] == 2:
                #etc
```

Comment: When I use this code, for some reason, the player doesn't get set as a variable in the game. Like, I set a self.player variable as a instance of a player sprite, but the game class doesn't recognize the player as an actual part of itself, and won't run when I use this. Do I have to return it from this or something?

Answer (score 0):

import csv

```
    #LOADING A MAP DATA
    with open("YOUR CSV FILE") as f:
        data = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        y = 0
        for row in data:
            x = 0
            for column in range(len(row)):
                x += 1

                #IF THE TILE IS IN THE ROW THEN WE RENDERING IT
                if row[column] == "-1":
                    #Render your tile here
      
                    display.blit(image, (x * your tile width, y * your tile height , tile width size, tile height size))

            y += 1
```